# Xamarin Forms set Android in Light

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, styles, themes

I can't find even with Google how to set the Android project into Light Theme.

The Toolbar behind the 'dotted' button stays black, how do I get it white?

I mean the navigation that pops up when u press the 'dotted' button on the right top.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <color name="ListViewSelected">#ff9933</color>
  <color name="ListViewHighlighted">#E39696</color> 

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
    <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff9933</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff9933</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff9933</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff9933</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom theme in droid/resource/styles.xml. and also need to apply this theme in your MainActivity

**Apply Theme on MainActivity**

```
[Activity(Label = "YourProject.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

**Add a custom theme in Style.XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarPopupTheme">@style/CustomActionBarPopupTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomActionBarPopupTheme" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have that what you posted, but the background of the toolbaritem list stays dark.

Comment: @user7849697, I have added CustomActionBarPopupTheme for toolbar theme. Please see my updated answers. and also configure it in the main style.

Comment: I used the code you provided but it still stays dark. Watch the image I uploaded.

Comment: Please share your style.xml.

Comment: You didn't add CustomActionBarPopupTheme in your style file. also add  **<item name="android:actionBarPopupTheme">@style/CustomActionBarPopupTheme</item>** see my code, you miss some lines

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be better off writing a little bit of platform-specific code:

**Android**

On your MainActivity.cs write code in the overridden OnCreate method code look like :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);            
            LoadApplication(new App());
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, 0, 0, 0)); //here
        }
```

Comment: Yes I know how to change the color of the toolbar, but i'm talking about the toolbaritems background if you press the 'dotted' button!